# What's the correct HTML markup to use for headers for groups of table rows?

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility

I have a single table with rows that are grouped, and there should be a header above each group. What is the correct markup for this when it comes to semantics and accessibility?

I'm aware of the `scope` attribute for `<th>` elements, and I'm thinking the `rowgroup` and `colgroup` might be related to this, but I don't understand how to actually apply it properly, or whether the `<td>` or `<tbody>` elements need some attributes applied to them as well.

Here is an example table, without any accessibility attributes:

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center }
thead { background: #ccc }
th, td { padding: 0.25em 0.5em; border: 1px solid #ddd }
tbody th { background: #eee }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Group 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Gruppe 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Gruppe 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: rowgroup and colgroup are not shown on the UI. But you can use them as role with ARIA. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/rowgroup_role

Comment: I'm aware of the aria roles, but I was talking about the allowed values for the `scope` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th#scope

Comment: @Svish don’t forget that a [table](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#table) also needs an accessible name. Screen readers build an index of all tables on the page, that users can navigate. Therefore they need a name. It can be provided f.e. by means of `aria-label` or [`<caption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption).

Comment: @Andy Don't remind me  Just kidding, yeah, I'm aware of those. Unfortunately can't just add those, as it needs a bit of input from design and editor, but thanks for the reminder to create an issue in our tracker for that. All our tables are currently missing captions, but they usually have a header right before it, which makes it a bit awkward to also add a caption which would say basically the same thing as is in the header... any advice on that? Is it possible to link a table to a header element instead of having a caption for example?

Comment: Of course, in that case you would [use `aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby) to reuse the visible heading as the table’s name. `<h2 id="myheading">… <table aria-labelledby="myheading" …`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scope="rowgroup"` would be the correct markup.

You already did a great job and used several `<tbody>` elements to group rows.

Don’t forget that a [table](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#table) also needs an accessible name, which you can provide by means of `aria-label` or `<caption>`.

[The HTML Spec mentions for `rowgroup`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#attr-th-scope-rowgroup):

> The *row group* state means the header cell applies to all the remaining cells in the row group. A `th` element's `scope` attribute must not be in the row group state if the element is not anchored in a row group.

So how exactly does one mark up a row group?

[ARIA in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-tbody) mentions that the the default element for the `rowgroup` role is `<tbody>`, as it’s already used in the question.

```
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" scope="rowgroup">Group 2</th>
    </tr>
```

The [row group concept in the HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#concept-row-group) further mentions that also `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` establish such row groups.

The next question, then, is how browsers and screen readers actually expose this rowgroup. For concepts like `section` roles, the boundaries are announced, so when you navigate inside a new group, its name is announced. `rowgroup` is derived from `section`, so this behaviour would seem appropriate as well.

I doubt that a lot of screen readers actually announce this. I will look into this, if anybody has results to share already, that would be great.

- Firefox 112 does not expose the row group in the accessibility tree, but the `rowheader` for the `<th>`. NVDA 2023.1 then does not announce it.

Here’s a sandbox for testing:

```html
<table>
  <caption>Table for testing row group headings</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" scope="rowgroup">Group 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" scope="rowgroup">Group 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sidenote: The `dir` attribute is not mentioned in the [table's _4.9.12 Processing Model_ specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#table-processing-model), and does therefore not affect the relation of data and header cells as written in the HTML source code. The `dir` attribute only affects visual placement (i.e. layout) of the cells.

Comment: I guess "These cells can be placed to the right or the left of the header" is what confuses me here, because it sounds like it would then apply only to cells in the same row as the rowgroup? While in this case the cells the header applies to are _below_ the header, not to the right or left of it 

Comment: @Svish The `tbody` element is the row group; it _groups rows_. The `th` element is a header cell, whose _scope_ is limited to its current _row group_ via `scope="rowgroup"`; the header itself is not a row group. I hope this clears up your confusion.

Comment: I guess the MDN needs some improvement? I replaced the reference with the one from the HTML specification, which seems more clear. Do you agree?

Comment: The HTML specification's "row group" specifically refers to the concept of the table model. The ARIA-role refers to an element's role as exposed by the browser; the ARIA-role does not and cannot affect how `scope="rowgroup"` is processed. You may want to link to the [concept _row group_](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#concept-row-group) of the table model; it also mentions `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` as elements corresponding to row groups.

Comment: @OskarGrosser Yeah, that's clearer actually, and it's also an example there with separate `tbody` and `th scope="rowgroup"`, so it seems this is indeed the correct solution, thank you 

Answer (score 1):

You have divided the data into [row groups](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#concept-row-group) with `tbody` elements.

**Use `scope="rowgroup"`** on the `th` element to apply that header only to the remaining data of the same row group.

Or (as very verbose alternative), **explicitly associate headers to data cells** by listing each header by its ID in the data cell's [`headers` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#headers).

---

Row group headers apply to all remaining data cells in the same row group, where "remaining" means: The cells whose slots' x- and y-coordinates are greater than or equal to the header's slots'.

Or in other words: All cells that are part of the *rectangle* bounding the header cell and the row group's 'highest' slot (where 'highest' means: hightest x- and y-coordinate); the row group's slot in the bottom-right corner (in left-to-right top-to-bottom writing direction).

Section [*4.9.10 The `th` element*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-th-element) of the HTML specification contains a note showing which headers apply to which slots, including row group headers. **For visual reference**, see the bright-green branching arrows:

[image: A table with row groups and row group headers, with arrows indicating which headers apply to which slots.]

Or see this interactive table which highlights all affected cells for a clicked header:

```js
const table = document.querySelector("table");
table.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const header = evt.target.closest("th");
  if (!header) return;
  
  const headerCoordinates = getCoordinatesOf(header);
  
  // Specific to this table
  const isColumnHeader = headerCoordinates.y === 0;  
  const isRowHeader = !isColumnHeader && headerCoordinates.x === 1;
  const isRowGroupHeader = header.getAttribute("scope") === "rowgroup";
  
  for (let row of table.rows) {
    for (let cell of row.cells) {
      const cellCoordinates = getCoordinatesOf(cell);
      
      const followsColumnHeader = isColumnHeader && cellCoordinates.x === headerCoordinates.x
        && cellCoordinates.y >= headerCoordinates.y;
      const followsRowHeader = isRowHeader && cellCoordinates.y === headerCoordinates.y
        && cellCoordinates.x >= headerCoordinates.x;
      
      // Specific to this table
      const hasSameRowGroup = cell.closest("tbody") === header.closest("tbody");
      const followsHeader = cellCoordinates.x >= headerCoordinates.x
        && cellCoordinates.y >= headerCoordinates.y;
      const followsRowGroupHeader = hasSameRowGroup && isRowGroupHeader && followsHeader;
      
      const shouldHighlight = followsColumnHeader || followsRowHeader || followsRowGroupHeader;
      
      cell.classList.toggle("highlight", shouldHighlight);
      cell.classList.toggle("rowgroup", followsRowGroupHeader);
      cell.classList.toggle("column", !followsRowGroupHeader && followsColumnHeader);
      cell.classList.toggle("row", !followsRowGroupHeader && followsRowHeader);
    }
  }
});

function getCoordinatesOf(cell) {
  return {
    x: cell.cellIndex,
    y: Array.from(cell.closest("table").rows).indexOf(cell.parentElement)
  };
}

// Allow keyboard interaction
for (let row of table.rows) {
  for (let cell of row.cells) {
    if (cell.tagName !== "TH") continue;
    cell.tabIndex = 0;
  }
}
table.addEventListener("keydown", evt => {
  if (evt.code === "Enter") evt.target.click();
});
table.addEventListener("keyup", evt => {
  if (evt.code === "Space") evt.target.click();
});
```

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: large;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
th {cursor: default}

.highlight.column {background-color: orange}
.highlight.rowgroup {background-color: lightgreen}
.highlight.row {background-color: aquamarine}
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr> <th> ID <th> Measurement <th> Average <th> Maximum
 <tbody>
  <tr> <td> <th scope=rowgroup> Cats <td> <td>
  <tr> <td> 93 <th> Legs <td> 3.5 <td> 4
  <tr> <td> 10 <th> Tails <td> 1 <td> 1
 <tbody>
  <tr> <td> <th scope=rowgroup> English speakers <td> <td>
  <tr> <td> 32 <th> Legs <td> 2.67 <td> 4
  <tr> <td> 35 <th> Tails <td> 0.33 <td> 1
</table>
```